# html validation on button or hidden filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

wondering if anyone can help. As part of a form, i'm using a selection of buttons to capture satisfaction, rather than radio or dropdown. I'm using a jquery to capture the value of the button and adding it to a hidden field - the field the form is using to submit the information.

All works fine, however, i want to put validation, to make sure an answer is captured - but HTLM5 validation does not support buttons or hidden fields. Is there a was i can use JS to check if a button has been pressed on submit, and if not, toggle the html validator for that field?

Here the code i have so far;

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label required input_satisfaction" for="feedbackQuestions[56]">Please rate the venue facilities: <span class="required ">*</span></label>
<input required="required" type="hidden" name="feedbackQuestions[56]" id="feedbackQuestions_56">
<div id="feedbackQuestions_56_group" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"><button class="satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" required="required" name="Questions[56][0]" value="Excellent">Excellent</button></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><button class="satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" required="required" name="Questions[56][1]" value="Good">Good</button></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><button class="satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" required="required" name="Questions[56][2]" value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</button></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><button class="satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" required="required" name="Questions[56][3]" value="Poor">Poor</button></div>
</div>
    <script>
            $('#feedbackQuestions_56_group .satisfactionBtn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#feedbackQuestions_56_group .satisfactionBtn').each(function( index ) {
                    $( this ).removeClass('active');
                });
                var thisval = $(this).val();
                $('#feedbackQuestions_56').val(thisval);
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
          </script>
</div>
```

I know i need to add a trigger to the submit button futher down the page, so i can do a jquery .click() and then prevent the event until i've checked, but not sure how to actually check or how to trigger the validation.

Comment: Why don't you do custom validation on your value in hidden field ?

Comment: What do you mean by custom validation? Hidden field don't support the required attr unfortunately.

Comment: I could use the val() of the hidden field as my check to see if it's been answered - but how would I then trigger a validation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that hidden field value is filled by code not user, code should validate the value(or no need to validate).

It sounds really strange that the hidden field need to be validated.

**Edited**

If you really need to validate **hidden** field, the original way is not working, but you can do it tricky by just add **opacity:0** style.

Add such style make it invisible but not hidden, so the validate should work fine as usual.

But just remember you must change the **type="hidden"** to **type="text"**

Comment: My question is, how do I validate that. Hidden field is only used to capture the value to allow the data to be captured in the post, as buttons inherently don't hold data. User is making a choice, I just need to make sure they make a choice

Comment: This should be a comment. The hidden field could have been displayed before and therefore need validation. You don't know the use case of the OP.

Comment: I see what you mean - it's a bit hooky - but it would work!

Comment: hope that will help you

Answer (score 1):

I would actually store it as a global JS variable rather than a hidden field.  you can reparse this value to the hidden field through jQuery if you want, but I don't see a use in that.  Also divs are selectable in JS as well, so you do not need them to be   just one or the other.

```js
var isSelected = false;
            $('#feedbackQuestions_56_group .satisfactionBtn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#feedbackQuestions_56_group .satisfactionBtn').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
                var thisval = this.id;
                console.log("thisval: " + thisval);
                $('#feedbackQuestions_56').val(thisval);
                $(this).addClass('active');
                isSelected = true
            });

            $('#onSubmit').click(function () {
                console.log(isSelected);

                //
                // Look into ajax post command
                //


                if (isSelected == true) {
                    //    ajax call here
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select a rating")
                }

            })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required input_satisfaction" for="feedbackQuestions[56]">Please rate the venue facilities:
            <span class="required ">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="feedbackQuestions_56_group" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  name="Questions[56][0]" id="Excellent">Excellent
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  name="Questions[56][1]" id="Good">Good
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  name="Questions[56][2]" id="Satisfactory">Satisfactory
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 satisfactionBtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  name="Questions[56][3]" id="Poor">Poor
            </div>

            <div class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="onSubmit">Submit</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @gsusonline it also looks like the jQuery .val() is not intended for what you are using it for, it should work now with id instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - would need to amend as this isn't the only form type of this on the page, so would need to amend the global variable part - but elegant solution!

Comment: @gsusonline,is it good enough for an upvote, or an answered? 
If you have more fields I would recommend collecting them all into a JavaScript Object vice a variable, and then validating that all fields of the JavaScript object are populated before posting the form through ajax.  Did you get a chance to read up on ajax?  It is very powerful.